# How to call specific properties file in spring

Tags: spring, file, properties

I have 3 properties file say propA, propB, and propC defined application-context.xml.

I need to call specific prop files . say for class A i need to call propA, for class B i need to call propB , for class C i need to call propC.

But that is not happening ..it keeps on loading propA all time for all classes.

I used

```
@PropertySource("classpath:propA.properties")
public class A {
@Override
@LoginLogout(skip=true)
public void execute(Webdriver driver)  {
    execute (driver);
}
```

}

Comment: What to do when there is multiple prop file of same key but diff values. and to be loaded in respective classes.

@PropertySource("classpath:propA.properties")
class A
{
fdsf();
}

@PropertySource("classpath:propB.properties")
class B
{
fdsf();
}

but as in applicationcontext.xml
<values>classpath:propA.properties<values>
<values>classpath:propB.properties<values>

But the issue is that it is always overloading PropB values.

How to deal with this ?

Answer (score 0):

In class B use:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:propB.properties")
```

In class C use:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:propC.properties")
```

Comment: I did the same thing but it is always loading the last prop value for all classes.....